# How to add multible @app.route in py editor?

Tags: python, charts, bottle

Hear is my code:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask import Markup
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def chart():
    labels = ["2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4","2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4","2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4"]
    values = [9,6,6,10,9,7,5,4,10,6,10,8]
    return render_template('chart.html', values=values, labels=labels)


@app.route("/chart")
def chart():
    labels = ["2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4","2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4","2009-Q1","2009-Q2","2009-Q3","2009-Q4"]
    values = [9,6,6,10,9,7,5,4,10,6,10,8]
    return render_template('chart.html', values=values, labels=labels)





if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001)
```

The first `@app.route("/")`  works correctly the second does not disappear any Chart like the first one. it disappears just some text of HTML. Any one can help?

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to import Flask twice so you can delete one line of

```
from flask import Flask
```

The reason it's not working is because you defined two of the same functions 'chart()'. There also seems to be something wrong with the name 'chart' as a route, if you change that, it should be working.

Comment: I have change the one of two functions 'chart()'. to 'chart1()'. And its still the same.

Comment: You should also update the name 'chart' to something different, that way it should be working.

Comment: I update chart to something different and still didn't work.. The problem I thin is in there " @app.route('/') " because the first is working correctly and if I put something for example " @app.route('/chart') " or deferent names throw me an error.

Comment: yes if you change the second " @app.route('/chart') " to something other than '/chart' it should be working.